# What material should I use to hide a duct running just above the floor in a closet?

Tags: hvac, drywall, framing, ducts, soffit

I have an 8-inch HVAC duct running along the back corner of a closet (4 feet wide) at ground level. I assume a good way to hide it would be to build a frame of 2x4s. However, while drywall would work on the side, would it be strong enough along the top edge? Worried someone may stand on it one day and break through. Is plywood a better choice? Or are there fire-proofing considerations?

Comment: Can you put shelves on top? Either a full on bookcase, or just the raw shelves from a box store to protect the top and provide a nice surface; a mini-countertop.

Comment: Unless you "bury" the top under some sort of shelving/storage, be sure to put down a wood product (plywood/OSB) on the horizontal surface. Your concern about drywall breaking under foot is _very_ valid.

Comment: Horizontal surfaces facing up are **flooring**.  Drywall is only used on surfaces at or exceeding 90 degrees, where gravity does not permit things to be set on top of them.   Drywall is only chalk wrapped with paper, you can't expect miracles from it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used 1x2’s as the frame around ducts and plywood to make a shoe rack.

I usually use Sheetrock/ drywall to close in ceiling mounted ducts. No one knew or will know it is a duct if you disguise it and make it wide enough it become a feature.

I am sure you could use Sheetrock. make sure to have a shelf over it and there is less chance someone would step on it